# is it possible to set text for a Label from local file in bb cascades?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Now I am developing an application using bb cascades.We know that, it is possible to set strings contents such as text of a TextView etc... in layouts from String.xml file in Android.

Like this, is it possible to set texts in qml from any local file?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you are asking about translation see the [localization doc](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/internationalization/localization.html).

Comment: Why do you need this? Purpose defines what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want to do, however, you can definitely load data from .xml file from external source using the following code:

```
ListView {
    dataModel: XmlDataModel {
        source: "path/to/yourxmlname.xml"
    }
}
```

If you consider to access external data from c++, you can use the following code:

```
QFile file(QDir::currentPath() + "/path/to/your/file");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        qDebug() << "error opening file";
        return;
    }
    file.readall();
    file.close();
```

Then you can pass the data retreived to qml following the instruction:
http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/index.html